# Is it possible to get result from joined SQL query from several tables in C# with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am using .Net Core with C# and Entity Framework. I need to get data for reporting and it requires joins with several tables.

My question is, what is the best way to call the SQL query and pass the result to a client application?

Comment: There a several Linq methodes for this, e.g.: [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1), [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) and [GroupJoin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, it's the ORM's job to generate JOINs from entity relations. If you need joins you're either missing the appropriate relations or using the wrong entities. Entities aren't tables and LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. ORMs like EF are *bad* at reporting anyway - they are meant to Map Objects to Relational data, while reporting is just data, no objects and behavior. ORMs and LINQ simply *can't* generate complex reporting queries

Comment: For reporting queries it's usually far easier to write a view, stored procedure or function that executes the actual query and map its results to DTOs - in EF Core 3.1 you'd call them query types or keyless objects

Answer (score 0):

If the number of tables used is less than 3 or 4, we can use the EF join to get the data from multiple tables.

Sample linq Join

```
var q=(from pd in dataContext.tblProducts 
 join od in dataContext.tblOrders on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID 
 join ct in dataContext.tblCustomers 
 on new {a=od.CustomerID,b=od.ContactNo} equals new {a=ct.CustID,b=ct.ContactNo} 
 orderby od.OrderID 
 select new { 
 od.OrderID,
 pd.ProductID,
 pd.Name,
 pd.UnitPrice,
 od.Quantity,
 od.Price,
 Customer=ct.Name //define anonymous type Customer
 }).ToList();
```

If the number of tables used is more than that I suggest you to implement a Stored Procedure and use it to get the data. You can still use the EF to call the SPROC and bind the data to any custom DTO class.

Comment: We don't - we create appropriate relations and let the ORM generate the JOINs. ORMs aren't meant for complex reporting though - in that case it's better to create a view or stored procedure and map to it. The choice depends on the usage scenario, not the number of tables. You can't create row numbers or running averages in LINQ even with a single table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - What do you think about LinqToDb? In this ORM, you [can](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-%28Analytic-Functions%29.html) create row numbers or running averages in LINQ

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I think it looks worse than the equivalent SQL query and you still aren't sure what the generated SQL will look like. That link is based on Oracle functions too - what will it generate for SQL Server? *No* database follows the SQL standard and windowing functions is one of the parts with the most differences